# Warbler with multiple executables

Tags: ruby, jruby, warbler

I am using [warbler](http://caldersphere.rubyforge.org/warbler/) to package my ruby project into an executable .jar file. In my project's Rakefile I list multiple ruby executables. However, when I build the jar with warbler, only the first executable (listed in my Rakefile) is launched when running `java -jar myjar.jar`. My current workaround for this is to have one launcher script in my project's bin folder that delegates to the other scripts based on the user's selection. Is there a better way to do this with warbler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is just a bug/new feature depending on your view point :). Care to file an issue at https://github.com/jruby/warbler/issues?